# nightmare - ввод в input кириллицы и отображение результата

Tags: javascript, node.js, кириллица

Делаю запрос c nodejs nightmare на некий сайт. В поле num нужно вводить буквенно-цифровые символы. Если использовать латинские символы, то они вставляются, кириллица - нет. Сохранение файла в utf-8 и вставка в `.goto`  параметра `header 'content=text/html; charset=utf-8'` не помогло.

Также с результатом. На реальном сайте в msg возвращается текст на кириллице, через скрипт null.

Собственно код:

```js
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
})

nightmare
  .goto('http://ssssite.ru//', 'content=text/html; charset=utf-8')
  .wait()
  .type('input[id="num"]', '')
  .type('input[id="num"]', '123ффффф123123236269')
  .wait(5000)
  .click('#buttsearchsts')
  .wait()
  .wait(5000)
  .evaluate(function() {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('msg');
  })
  .end()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log('11');
    console.log(result);
    console.log('22');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```